# How to extract text from the middle of a string in cell

Tags: excel, vba

So I was exporting a log from our server to a .csv file. I converted it to an .xlsm file to get the contents. I want to pull the user name that logged in from a given cell. All cells that I want to pull from have this format:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

New Logon:
    Security ID:        ZZZ\username
    Account Name:       username
-----------------------------
```

I want to pull the username from this cell and put it into the cell adjacent to create a pivot table of all those logging in.

How can I extract only the username?

Comment: The problem is that all of the usernames are different lengths...

Comment: Use InStr() to get the positions of bounding fields then you should know the length for the mid() call

Comment: Then do `mid([cell],5,len([cell])` or you could always cheat and use any number like 100.

Comment: If there is really only one \ then try `split` by \ and use the second result.

Comment: Is this username repeating after a fixed number of rows like 9, 18,27 or t varies. Which column ie. C or D etc. it is written. Can you upload snapshot of the file to some of the loading sites like Drop Box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub getUserName()

    Const COL   As Long = 1
    Const AN    As String = "Account Name:"

    Dim ur As Range, v As Variant, i As Long, x As String

    Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    v = ur.Columns(COL).Resize(ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count - 1, 2)
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        x = Right(v(i, 1), Len(v(i, 1)) - (InStrRev(v(i, 1), AN) - 1))
        x = Trim(Mid(x, Len(AN) + 1))
        v(i, 2) = Left(x, InStr(x, vbLf) - 1)
    Next
    ur.Columns(COL).Resize(ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count - 1, 2) = v
End Sub
```

---

Currently setup to extract from column A to column B